# RestSharp for testing Rest Api: Unable to authorize rest api with Oauth2. Not sure what needs to be done

Tags: c#, restsharp, azure-devops-rest-api

I have recently started to learn Rest Api automation testing using RestSharp. I was able to perform basic test for some rest api. However for the same test as part of new build developers have added authorization feature which is Oauth2. I am not sure how and where to implement it. I have attached very basic get test and some information which might be need for you to help me.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
using RestSharp;
using System.Net;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace RestApiTest
{
    [CodedUITest]
    public class TestApi
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetApi()
        {
            //https://XYZtestsample.azurewebsites.net/ - previous link, without authorization it works fine when passed as Restclient argument 
           
           
           
           var client = new RestClient("http://XYZarsuitewswagger-XYZarsuitestaging.azurewebsites.net/"); //--- This one has authentication header and does not work.

            //HttpBasicAuthenticator obj = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("XYZ.XYZ@in.XYZ.com", "XYZ@2019");            

           
           
           var request = new RestRequest("/XYZARSuiteAPI/v1/BUProfiles", Method.GET);
           
           
           
           
           // request.AddHeader("XYZ.XYZ@in.XYZ.com", "XYZ@2019");

            
            
            
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;         
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

             //new OAuth2Authenticator("XYZ.XYZ@in.abb.com", "XYZ@2019");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;         
        }
```

Below information I can see in Rest Api

[Rest Api Authorization Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hdO7.png)

[Rest Api Request Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tdMN.png)

UPDATE: I have authorize option available in the sample UI given to check the output when I authorized it I got below info

curl -X GET "http://XYZarsuitewswagger-XYZarsuitestaging.azurewebsites.net/XYZARSuiteAPI/v1/BUProfiles" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDSURXTVRQdlp5SjZ0eC1DRHh3MCIsImtpZCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDSURXTVRQdlp5SjZ0eC1DRHh3MCJ9.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.rJ1VDhjE3NDMnW5pdv8N02OsKX3vKBO0bTxo2Lx_KZWq6eMi1DAvTXNd49tZhCJTr-PrCwbwsZsvf3fye_fNjL2VthlOA40UsvbPkou-F_b3B2kK3jzAdn8icbNEw5-3cxx8nAKiuDVZeRMTa3KVj0Kd384Eb6ZO5JBf4evoMCNMidrVAeKbxcP0B2tF8Aw1cgDWswNqghCUjb9foxxVIP-7MFeNFpuxGvLjtcQHIgY9VqMMpYBpE5DYLjqX0yXkGqBWnD4v-590wYtH0YPB-XOOtKZsy280PEHMock8jlLQdBNOp0w9SVw7XLfy5p0vp3ovHZqbb9IbSHQy-frV4g"

Thank you.

Comment: You have to set Authenticator property on RestClient object or add proper headers manually

Comment: Hi Wokuo, Thanks for the reply. As I am a beginner with RestSharp automation testing I am not sure how to do that. Will it be possible for you to share a sample code spinet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Authenticator property on RestClient object. Also it is important to add Accept header on the RestRequest object, not sure if it would be json in your case, but you can set here any valid content type.

Sample:

```
var client = new RestClient("<your_base_url>");
client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator("<your_access_token>", "Bearer");

var request = new RestRequest("<your_query>", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```